# React: rename this.context in a class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm trying to assign another name to context in a class component to customize my code.

```
static contextType = MyContext;

this.customContext = this.context;
```

I also tried to assign it in the constructor.

but I receive undefined customContext (this.context returns right value).

Comment: Does the class have a [contextType](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype) property? For example, `static contextType = /*something*/`

Comment: @NicholasTower  
yes of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to rename the context in class components.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `this.context` have value?
Maybe you assigning to `customContext` variable that are not yet passed?

Comment: yes, it has a few objects.